# iText7: Variable Background images, footers, and possible growing content

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am trying to dynamically build a PDF using iText 7.  The conditions for the PDF are:

1. Some of the pages will have a footer.
2. The background image on the pages will vary.
3. The content on a given page may extend past one page.

While I have been able to get these working individually, I have not been able to get them working in one straight pass of processing the data to be contained in the PDF.

Is this possible to do in one pass of the data or do I need to stitch together various documents in order to make this work?

Edit: To add things that I have tried using the Document API:

1. Events (Following the XofY example from iText). During tests, this appears to be only executed on the close of pages at the close of the document. This means I don't know if a page that shouldn't have a page number overflowed.
2. Leveraging the ColumnRenderer.  However, this caused a problem with the background image, and given that not all pages have the same background image it was leading to a problem with identifying which background image goes on which page (I believe a custom renderer will be the direction that needs to be used, but I'm not sure how to make it work in full detail - e.g. the overflow to next page must trigger the adding of the page number, the adding of the new background image, and additional work.  I tried using the BackgroundImage event tying to the JSON Templating I built, but again, when the content spanned multiple pages, there were issues.
3. The tables that are used have different background pages given the type of data that will be shown and potentially other images throughout the page based on the data that is displayed.

Final thoughts: I realize this is "vague".  And I wish I had code that provided any value.  The thing I'm leaning toward doing (which I really don't) is making multiple PDF Documents with the appropriate characteristics and then merging them all.  This feels like it should be unnecessary. (as mkl noted).

Edit 2: Removed the JSON template and here's a sample to demonstrate the end of page processing:

EventHanlder:

```
public class PageNumber implements IEventHandler {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        System.out.println("[handleEvent]"+ ((PdfDocumentEvent)event).getType());
    }
}
```

Main:

```
      document.setMargins(itsTemplate.getMargin().getTop(),
                itsTemplate.getMargin().getRight(), itsTemplate.getMargin().getBottom(),
                itsTemplate.getMargin().getLeft());

        pdf.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, new PageNumber());
        ArrayList<Page> pages = itsTemplate.getPages();
        for (Page page: pages) {
           pdf.addNewPage(PageSize.LETTER);
            System.out.println("[main]Adding paragraph");
          //  processContent(page.getContainers());
            Paragraph p = new Paragraph().add("this is a test")
                            .setWidth(document.getPdfDocument().getLastPage().getPageSize().getWidth())
                    .setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
           document.add(p);
            if (pages.indexOf(currentPage) < (pages.size() - 1)) {
                System.out.println("[main] Adding new page");
                //pdf.addNewPage(PageSize.LETTER);
                document.add(new AreaBreak(AreaBreakType.NEXT_PAGE));
                System.out.println("[main]  new page added");
            }
        }
document.close()
```

Both the system.out and walking through the debugger show that the end of page event is processed during the document close.

System out:

```
[main]Adding paragraph
[main] Adding new page
[main]  new page added
[handleEvent]EndPdfPage
[handleEvent]EndPdfPage
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Indeed, please make clear what problem exactly you ran into. In general requirements like yours can be fulfilled by using `Document` to add content to and page events for footers and backgrounds.

Comment: *"this appears to be only executed on the close of pages at the close of the document. This means I don't know if a page that shouldn't have a page number overflowed."* - No, by default page events are not executed that late (except for the last page - obviously - and probably the one before that); have you changed anything that might change the default behavior? Also don't forget to evaluate the properties of the page event.

Comment: *"I realize this is "vague"."* - Indeed, it is vague. To create a less vague question, you should try to implement your requirements. If you run into a problem, reduce your code to a simple program still illustrating the problem and post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working with a combination of renderers and events.  In the renderer which dealt with custom data arrays, I added the current template page information to a variable and then triggered an event that was triggered at the end of pages.  Given I had disabled automatic flushing and manual flush, there was a bit of tweaking that had to go on there (I wish I kept the URL for it but wasn't sure if it work completely as I experienced some issues even after applying that recommendation).

This is a partial code set.  The full code set will be open-sourced when other components are completed:

```
public class PDFReportGenerator implements ReportProcessor {
   private  LayoutInfo info;

   private generate() {
        pdf.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, new PageNumber(info, this));
        pdf.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, new Link(info, this));

   }
```

The LayoutInfo class:

```
public class Link implements IEventHandler  {
    private final LayoutInfo info;
    private final PDFReportGenerator generator;

    public Link(LayoutInfo info, PDFReportGenerator generator) {
        this.info = info;
        this.generator = generator;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<LinkDetails>> links = info.getLinks();

        PdfPage page = ((PdfDocumentEvent) event).getPage();
        int pageNumber = page.getDocument().getPageNumber(page);

        if (links.containsKey(pageNumber)) {
            ArrayList<LinkDetails> linkList = links.get(pageNumber);
            for (LinkDetails link:linkList) {
                Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(link.getLocation().getX(),link.getLocation().getY(),
                        link.getSize().getWidth(),link.getSize().getHeight());
                PdfLinkAnnotation annotation = new PdfLinkAnnotation(rectangle);
                if (link.isBorder())
                    annotation.setBorderStyle(PdfAnnotation.STYLE_SOLID);
                PdfAction action = PdfAction.createURI(link.getUrl());
                annotation.setAction(action);
                page.addAnnotation(annotation);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

```
public class Link implements IEventHandler  {
    private final LayoutInfo info;
    private final PDFReportGenerator generator;

    public Link(LayoutInfo info, PDFReportGenerator generator) {
        this.info = info;
        this.generator = generator;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<LinkDetails>> links = info.getLinks();

        PdfPage page = ((PdfDocumentEvent) event).getPage();
        int pageNumber = page.getDocument().getPageNumber(page);

        if (links.containsKey(pageNumber)) {
            ArrayList<LinkDetails> linkList = links.get(pageNumber);
            for (LinkDetails link:linkList) {
                Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(link.getLocation().getX(),link.getLocation().getY(),
                        link.getSize().getWidth(),link.getSize().getHeight());
                PdfLinkAnnotation annotation = new PdfLinkAnnotation(rectangle);
                if (link.isBorder())
                    annotation.setBorderStyle(PdfAnnotation.STYLE_SOLID);
                PdfAction action = PdfAction.createURI(link.getUrl());
                annotation.setAction(action);
                page.addAnnotation(annotation);
            }

        }
    }
}
```